# How to select a specific woocommerce category archive to display short description for products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have added the following code to display short description on Woocommerce product archive pages:

```
function webroom_add_short_description_in_product_categories() {
global $product;
if ( ! $product->get_short_description() ) return;
?>
<div itemprop="description">
    <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $product->get_short_description() ) ?>
</div>
<?php
}
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'webroom_add_short_description_in_product_categories', 5);
```

However - I would like to be able to select only specific product categories for this code, so I can select the categories I want the short description  to display on.
How can I do this please?

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'webroom_add_short_description_in_product_categories');
function webroom_add_short_description_in_product_categories() {
    global $product;
    // get product categories by product id
    $product_categories = get_the_terms( $product->get_id(), 'product_cat' );
    // set default state if product has category set by you or not
    $has_category = false;
    // set which category to display short description
    $categories = [
        'Accessories',
        'Bags',
        'Clothing',
    ];
    // check if product categories is in array
    if ( $product_categories ) {
        foreach ( $product_categories as $product_category ) {
            if ( in_array( $product_category->name, $categories ) ) {
                // set true if product has category set by you
                $has_category = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if ( ! $product->get_short_description() || ! $has_category ) return;
    ?>
    <div itemprop="description">
        <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $product->get_short_description() ) ?>
    </div>
<?php }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).